# laravel - Using unllink to delete file, receive is a directory error

Tags: php, laravel

Helo.

I have a question. Just now, when I tried to delete a picture using only unlink without the @ symbol, it returned the "unlink is a directory" error. What is the reason that causes it? I received an advice that using the symbol @ to the unlink is a bad practice, but somehow this is the method that works.

```
$file = $request->file('image');

        if($file->getSize() < 2048000){
            $path = storage_path('app/public/' . $event->img);
                if (file_exists($path)) {
                    unlink($path);
                }
        $filename = Str::uuid() . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $event->img = $request->image->storeAs('events', $filename, 'public');
        }

        // Create and save post with validated data
        $event->save();
```

Comment: Did you turn on PHP errors and full warning messages.

Comment: `file_exists` will be true for a directory as well. Might event->img be empty?

Comment: @Jesse thank you for pointing that out. That was the culprit.

Comment: @cleopatez no worries, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, it is possible that one of the image names is empty and **unlink** is trying to delete a directory instead of file. **unlink** is only used to delete files and not directories. If you try to delete a directory using unlink, you will get an error. See the [documentation for unlink](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp).

The **file_exists** function checks whether a file or directory exists. Since you want to check if file exists and not directory, then you should use the [is_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) function instead of **file_exists**. See the documentation for [is_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).

Comment: I have the exact same scenario for an update method, which is using the for loop to check if there's any image on that particular field, if a new image is uploaded to that field,  it will continue to save, and continue to iterate to the next count of other image field. Yet this error still occured. Any suggestions? @NadirLatif

Comment: Try using `is_file` instead of `file_exists`. Does it fix the error ?